# Splitting a text file by number of lines, not size

Tags: windows-10, total-commander

Using [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) you can split files by byte size, but that's obviously indiscriminate towards the content.

[image]

> Is it possible to split files by number of lines instead?

*Using Total Commander or some other tool.*

Comment: Do any of the Powershell solutions here work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell  What is the maximum file size?

Answer (score 1):

Using busybox head and tail will help
https://frippery.org/busybox/

example sources, (you can cat or type or pipe your files):
`busybox seq 1 100`

first 50 lines:
`busybox seq 1 100 | busybox head -50`

last 50 lines:
`busybox seq 1 100 | busybox tail -50`

41<sup>st</sup> to 50<sup>th</sup> lines:
`busybox seq 1 100 | busybox head -50 | busybox tail -10`